# Laravel application: serve static files from outer public directory

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application in a directory:

```
/var/www/html/example/
```

The public folder of the site is:

```
/var/www/html/example/public/
```

I have a folder outer public folder with images, css/js and other files:

```
/var/www/html/example/application/themes/
```

I want to serve these files from this folder as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/themes/
```

Here is the current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]</IfModule>
```

Can you help me with the completition of the htaccess file, to serve the files from within the outer public folder. I made a few tests, but I get 500 or 400 errors.

Comment: any reason why not using public folder

Comment: yes. we have other files and settings too, and we need to keep them in the same place. (in application/ folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you want to do that, seems to me like it's not a good idea. But if you really need this, the simpliest way to do that is to use symbolic links.

```
ln -s /var/www/html/example/application/themes/ /var/www/html/example/public/themes/
```

Comment: Any way to do what Zoli wants is not good practice. ) But maybe he has a reason to do that.

Comment: why it not a good practice? where could I keep my application files together?

Comment: Sorry guys I will pull my word back, if OP can use this solution that is fine, the only thing is to document how you did it, in case you move your solution to other server.

Comment: will the simlink solution work only for files in the theme directory of for folders too?

Comment: It will basically create an alias for whole folder, so all files and folders inside it will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the help!